# Antenna House Force Close on Use of "external-graphic"

Tags: base64, png, xsl-fo, antenna-house

I am editing a xsl style sheet which is currently in use. Put a piece of code to display a png image which is generated into base64 string. When I try to format the output by using the UI of Antenna House, it force closed. Code is copy from AH website

If I use a real external image file by the same tag, it can show without problem.
But, it just force close if I use the base64 string.

```
<fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2" display-align="after">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic  src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: What version of AH Formatter are you using?  It worked for me with AH Formatter V6.6.  The image is a 37x37 QR code.  Is that correct? (Note that you can get AH Formatter to generate QR codes from text or a URL if you have the barcode option installed.)

Comment: v2.3.2002. I know it is old, but that I cannot do anything about it. Also, I tried on v6.5 and it works. It seems the older version does have bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for the 'data:' scheme was added in AH Formatter V3.2, AFAICT.  You will have to update your AH Formatter version if you want to use the 'data:' scheme.

If you want to use an inline image, you could try using an SVG version of the QR code, but I have no information on the level of SVG support in V2.3.  Otherwise, you will have to use an external image file, which you stated is working without a problem.